# Java Converting List<Vehicle> to List<Object>

Tags: java, list, object

My applications consists of Vehicle class and Customer class where I have an interface to add delete and search for each.

Because of this I implemented my interface for add as follows:

```
public void add(Object newObject, List<Object> myList);
```

and therefore this accepts all objects. However when I am trying to pass a Vehicle list from my application I am getting an error as it is expecting an Object List. How can I convert my List to List and still update the lists.

This is my initialized list of allVehicles.

```
List<Vehicle> allVehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
```

This is the method I am using to add new Vehicle where I am getting the error on allVehicles.

```
addNewCycle.add(addNewCycle, allVehicles);
```

The method from the Vehicle class implemented from interface.

```
public void add(Object newObject, List<Object> myList) {
    myList.add((Vehicle)newObject);
}
```

My question is how can I cast this list to an Object list and update it on Vehicles List.

Comment: Instead of casting which pretty much throws type safety out of the window, consider learning more about generics.

Comment: **Why** did you write the interface to take `Object` (and for that matter, what's the point of having your own static wrapper for `List#add`)?

Comment: Think about this List<Object> really you need this? With List<Object> you are just making generics useless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using generics for your interface

```
public interface Adder<T> {
    public void add(T newObject, List<T> myList);
}
```

Then you can do this

```
public class Vehicle implements Adder<Vehicle> {
    @Override
    public void add(Vehicle newObject, List<Vehicle> myList) {
        myList.add(newObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
List<Vehicle> allVehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
// add some vehicles
List<Object> allVehicles1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
allVehicles1.addAll(allVehicles);
// now use allVehicles1
```

Comment: Does putting vehicles in a list of objects make a lot of sense?

Comment: I guess you're right, there should be better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the `Vehicle` into `Object` is really futile. A better option would be redesigning your interface to support generics for `add` method:

```
public <T> add (T data, List<T> list);
```

In this case, your class can easily support this:

```
interface Foo {
    public <T> boolean add(T data, List<T> list);
}

class Bar implements Foo {
    @Override
    public <Bar> boolean add(Bar data, List<Bar> list) {
        return list.add(data);
    }
}

public class TestBar {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
List<Bar> list = new ArrayList<>();
bar.add(bar, list);
    //prints the elements in the list
    //override toString method in Bar for a "nicer" result
System.out.println(list);
}
```

A better implementation would be:

```
class Adder implements Foo {
    @Override
    public <T> boolean add(T data, List<T> list) {
        //totally generic
        return list.add(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

the Collection are by default Objects but since 1.5 Sun adds new mechanism to deal with objects called Generics. In other words

If you write

```
ArrayList arr =new ArrayList();
```

without the generics it will work. Objects and this words for < 1.4 
If you have

```
List<Vehicle> allVehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
```

and you wanna transfer it to `ArrayList` of `Object`s

```
List noremalArray = new ArrayList(allVehicles);
```